# `which` fails with symlinks

Tags: macos, shell

I have two versions of `cmd` on my system: `/path1/cmd` and `/path2/cmd`.
In my `$PATH`, `path1` is before `path2`, but I want to execute `/path2/cmd` without affecting other commands.

I did

```
ln -s /path2/cmd ~/bin
```

and put `~/bin` in front of `$PATH`.

Now, the correct version of `cmd` is executed (`/path2/cmd`), and I know it because they have different outputs.

BUT `which cmd` still shows `/path1/cmd`.

EDIT: I tested with bash, sh and zsh.

Comment: Give `rehash` a whirl?

Comment: `rehash` doesn't change `which cmd`, it only changes `type cmd` -- because `which` is an external command, it doesn't know about internal shell state like hashed PATH lookups. (But then, for that same reason, `which` shouldn't be used or trusted in bash anyhow).

Comment: ...of course, that's assuming that the OP *is* using bash; they don't specify their shell in the question, and if it's zsh, *that* has an internal `which`.

Comment: I modified the question to say I tested with bash, sh and zsh.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, I suspected bash b/c of Mac tag, however covered zsh base with rehash (uncertainity signalled by ? on comment). The lack of working on sh, zsh, and bash is suspicious.

Comment: This happens when you put a literal tilde in your path. Here's [shellcheck's wiki](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2147) on the issue.

Comment: Ahh. Yeah. If the OP ran `PATH+=":~/bin"` instead of `PATH+=:~/bin` (so the tilde was added literally instead of expanded), that would cause the issue.

Comment: (...that said, a good question would show *the exact command* precisely as run, so we could be certain about that kind of quoting issue rather than needing to guess).

Comment: @thatotherguy I did `export PATH="~/bin:$PATH"`. Thank you a lot!